# How to sync my local database of my web app to database of my deployed web app?

Tags: django, database, web, synchronization, cloud

So my project is a school distributed system based on django web framework. My web app will be deployed in every school on their local computers. And all of the data on those computer will by synced with a main server on my side. What I want is how to implement a solution that would help me sync files/data with my server such that if some file/data is changed on a local computer it'll replicate itself in our server and if I change some file/data on my server, it'll update on those local computers whenever they get an internet connection.

Comment: Hi Hamza, welcome to StackOverflow, we need more details, like what server are you deploying the project, what Django version you are using, but before all that please show us what you have done so far, this would enable us to help you more. Do have a look at the SO's help site (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  :)

Comment: django 2.1.1, aws elasticbeanstalk. I already build the Django application but i haven't synch data from local server to  cloud server